# Node.js + PHP + MySQL VPS hosting

Tags: php, node.js, hosting, web-hosting, vps

I have a website that I am building that is coded in PHP and I use MySQL for the database, I am also using node.js for most everything, so my website cannot exist without it for the most part.

I have been with a small company (One that a friend of mine started up) and they have given me cheap VPS hosting, and they even setup everything on the server that I needed done (because I have no clue how to set up a server myself) I currently pay $15 per month for hosting, and would not want to pay anymore than that at this time. (As my website is still in development, so it's just for my own personal usage and sharing among some friends for testing and such).

I need a relatively cheap hosting provider that gives me basically 100% control of the server (as I have many needs that usually are not part of packages), and I would also like to be able to have them (or someone) set up the server for me.

Comment: What are the specs on the VPS you are getting for $15?  Its easy to find VPS hosting for near that cost, but it's unlikely you will get any server setup beyond basic OS install and here's your root password without paying signifigantly more.

Comment: I'm not actually sure what the specs were, (the company has actually been sold to another company, so everything is a mess right now, which is the reason for looking for new hosting) But, like I said before, I don't need very high specs, but whatever I can for around $15/month for now, since like I said it's mostly just for testing purposes at the moment.

Comment: Why not try [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/?refcode=6f680d1e7f05), they're really cheap.

Comment: I use them now, and I have for about a year. They are really cheap and great.

Answer (score 1):

why not just sign up amazon ec2 free for one year [Here](http://aws.amazon.com/free/)